# How to mark dynamically created option as used in options list

Tags: reactjs

I want to render options in select dynamically from the list.
If option already used I want to mark it as `isUsed: true`.
I mean change state of `<Wrapper />`

```
this.state = {
  options: {
    One: {value: "one", isUsed: false},
    Two: {value: "two", isUsed: false},
    Three: {value: "three", isUsed: false}
  }
```

What is the best way?

I'm trying to mark it using `componentDidMount()` using `markUsed()` (for testing purpose there is static key *"One"*), but how do I get the current mounted option, to mark dynamic key in `this.state`? 
I've tried to `console.log(this)` in `componentDidMount()`, but it seems like it doesn't contain current mounted option value.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Input extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount = () => {
    console.log(this);
    this.props.markUsed();
  }

    render() {
    let options = Object.keys(this.props.list).map((item,i) => {
      if (!this.props.list[item].isUsed) {
        return(
          <option key={i} value={this.props.list[item].value}>{item}</option>
        )
      }
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <select>
      {options}
      </select>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
    )
  }
}

class Wrapper extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.markUsed = this.markUsed.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      options: {
        One: {value: "one", isUsed: false},
        Two: {value: "two", isUsed: false},
        Three: {value: "three", isUsed: false}
      },
      inputs: []
    }

  }
  markUsed = () => {
    this.setState(prevState =>({
      options: {
        ...prevState.options,
        One: {
          ...prevState.options.One,
          isUsed: true
        }
      }
    }));
  }
  addInput = (e) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      inputs: [...prevState.inputs, {option: "", value: ""}],
    }));
  }
  render() {
    return(
        <div>
        {
          this.state.inputs.map((val, idx) => {
            return (
              <div key={idx}>
                <Input list={this.state.options} markUsed={this.markUsed} />
              </div>
            )
          })
        }
        <button type="button" onClick={this.addInput}>add</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Wrapper />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Explain in the question the desired behavior, what does it means "If option already used I want to mark it", how you define "used"

Comment: I mean to change this.state.options[option].isUsed value of Wrapper instance to `true`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic solution where you pass a `target` to be marked:

```
markUsed = target => {
  const [key, keyValue] = Object.entries(this.state.options).find(
    ([, keyValue]) => keyValue.value === target
  );
  keyValue.isUsed = true;
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    options: { ...prevState.options, [key]: keyValue }
  }));
};
```

Therefore you need to pass a target value like `one`,`two`,`three` etc.

```
class Input extends React.Component {
  state = {
    ...
  };
  render() {
    const { markUsed } = this.props;

    const options = Object.keys(this.props.list).map((item, i) => {
      if (!this.props.list[item].isUsed) {
        if (this.props.list[item].value === this.state.currValue) {
          markUsed(this.state.currValue);
        }
        return ...
      }
    });

    return (
      <>
        <select
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={e => {
            e.persist();
            const currValue = e.target.value;
            markUsed(currValue);
            this.setState({ currValue });
          }}
        >
          ...
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Q-57340992-CallBackFind]